# How do I show webform component labels in a chart using Views chart format?

Tags: 7, views, webforms, charts

Drupal 7.50, [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) 4.12, [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) 2.0, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 3.13, [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) 2.0, with Google Charts as the charting engine, so not Highcharts.

I have a webform that collects simple drop down list values for each question. The values are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. There are around 10 questions.

The labels for each component are not displayed on the chart. It seems the Label of the very last field added to the list is used for all fields, and they are only shown when the bar is hovered over.

I created a view and added the webform submission data fields then enabled aggregation and set the format to Chart. Limited the number of records in the pager settings to 1 (So we get just one Webform instance). Example below shows how the first series is called "Governance Framework" but when hovered over, the bar shows the last label "Organisational Structure1".

[image: View configuration and preview]

Can anyone advise how I can get the Webform Component Field labels to show up on the left of each of the bars, or fix the hover over issue? Many thanks!

P.s. not sure which module page I should log an issue, so any pointers on how to patch the relevant project would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at https://www.drupal.org/node/2261419 seems like it was fixed, but not for tooltips. So Ideally I would like to show just the correct labels rather than as tooltips (neither works atm).

Answer (score 0):

## Module involved

About your PS:

> ... not sure which module page I should log an issue, so any pointers on how to patch the relevant project would be appreciated.

No doubt possible: [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).

## Using tooltips

It sounds to me that you should have a look at [Pass library-specific options via existing #raw_options](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209467), which already provides a solution (using `#raw_options`) to what you're trying to get to work (ie: "tooltips"). For charting engine *Highcharts* it's already supported (and committed to the most recent ***dev*** version, which is the version I recommend), while for charting engine *Google Charts* (which you are using) you'd need to apply the **RTBC**-[patch attached to comment nr 9](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2209467-9--raw_options.patch). Obviously, after that patch is committed, using the *#raw_options* will continue to work (for either charting engine). And rest assured, this patch ***will*** (not ***might*** ...) make it.

With this **#raw_options** solution, [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) has a solution for using options that are specific for either of the supported charting engines (Google Charts or Highcharts). While still not deviating from a key design concept of the Charts module, which is that all supported charting options should work for either charting engines (you should be able to easily swap from one to the other charting engine, without your charts being affected).

**Notes**:

1. Apart from [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) (without **s**), there is also [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (with **s**). The results you'd get are probably going to be similar, because both modules use [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).
2. Drupal 7.50, which you are using, is the most recent Drupal version, but still your screenprint includes that (red) error msg with "*There is a security update available for your version of Drupal*"... bizarre ...

<sup><sup>Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.</sup></sup>

Comment: Hi Pierre, I have applied the patch from #9 on the issue, to the 7.x-2.0-rc1+5-dev version of Charts. I then set the Chart Settings to show labels and tooltips, but this hasn't changed the behaviour at all. It still shows the last Field's label and colour for all bars. Is there something more I need to do with the configuration of the View?  Thx for your help!

Comment: Oh, and you're right - I was on the previous release on my local dev machine..

Comment: Well, with that upgrade you at least got those Views UI options about labels and tooltips. And since that doesn't seem to solve your question, I did some extra digesting of your question ... A completely different way to try to get this to work (to put those charts together), is to work with what's called  "parent charts" and "child charts", as explained within [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929). More specifically what's detailed within the paragraph "Creating Multiple Series and Combo Charts in the UI". Should I post another answers about that?

Comment: Sorry Pierre, but I do not wish to create a complex chart with an overlay of another series. I just want each Field to be a bar, with it's relevant colour and key label (As it's configured to do). Is it due to Webform components being used as the Fields, rather than normal Entity Fields? The bars are also all the same colour as the last Field in the list.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed on this (how to best answer you). Maybe you should consider trying the [Webform ChartS](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (with "s" ...) as an alternative? Especially because of what it says on its project page: '***... integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data***'?

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks but I really need to create a View rather than use the Analysis tab (To pass contextual filters based on Author). Shall I log an issue on the "Charts" project page? I'm using Drupal 7.5 , Views 7.x-3.14, Charts 7.x-2.0-rc1+5-dev, and Webform 7.x-4.13.